# Using curlmirror.pl gives different outputs

Tags: perl, curl

Using [http://curl.haxx.se/programs/curlmirror.txt](https://web.archive.org/web/20130601193019/https://curl.haxx.se/programs/curlmirror.txt) [**Edit**: Current version at https://github.com/cudeso/tools/blob/master/curlmirror.txt ], I'm looking to download a website and check for changes between the newly downloaded website and one that I have downloaded previously. However when I download the same website sometimes the links on the website use relative paths, sometimes they use absolute paths, and that counts as a "change" even though the website did not change.

```
Usage: curlmirror.pl -l -d 3 -o someOutputFileDirectory/url http://url

Output 1: <td><a href="testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
Output 2: <td><a href="http://example.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
```

Is there a way to convert all relative paths to absolute paths or the other way around? I just need to standardize the download so that these links do not appear as "changes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I assume that the url is placed to `$url` variable. Then You can try something like bellow:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {$url="http://somedomain.org"}
s!(\b(?:url|href)=")([^/]+)(")!$1$url/$2$3!gi' << XXX
<td><a href="testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<td><a href="http://mydomain.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="home">
XXX
```

Output:

```
<td><a href="http://mymain.org/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<td><a href="http://mydomain.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="http://mymain.org/home">
```

It replaces all `href="..."` or `url="..."` (case-insensitive) patterns with `href="$url/..."` or `url="$url/..."` if `...` not contains `/` character.

If the input is a file, You can replace these patterns in the file directly:

```
cat >tfile << XXX
<td><a href="testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<td><a href="http://mydomain.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="home">
XXX

cat tfile
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN {$url="http://mymain.org"}
s!(\b(?:url|href)=")([^/]+)(")!$1$url/$2$3!gi' tfile
echo "---"
cat tfile
```

Output:

```
<td><a href="testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<td><a href="http://mydomain.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="home">
---
<td><a href="http://mymain.org/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<td><a href="http://mydomain.com/testing.htm">LINK</a></td>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="http://mymain.org/home">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really fix the issue. curlmirror.pl downloads the html as text, and it's not just <a href> tags, other links like <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="home"> become <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL="http://testing.com/home">. I need a way to make curlmirror download all the links as either absolute paths or relative paths